# Implementing sets of structs within a map of structs

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have a map of structs as follows:

```
type SocketID string
type Socket struct {
    socket //...
    id     string
}

type Channel struct {
    sync.Mutex
    sockets map[SocketID]Socket
}
```

I want to be able to add subchannels to it, where each `Socket` belongs to one subchannel. I tried changing the channel struct to this:

```
type SubchannelID string
type Channel struct {
    sync.Mutex
    sockets     map[SocketID]Socket
    subchannels map[SubchannelID]map[SocketID]Socket
}
```

But the problem I have with this is removing a `Socket` from the `Channel` becomes an O(n^2) operation, and each socket is duplicated between the `sockets` and `subchannels` maps. How would I optimize this while keeping the channels and subchannels abstracted away from the sockets?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, answer ended up being simple:

```
struct Channel {
    sync.Mutex
    sockets     map[SocketID]Socket
    subchannels map[SocketID]SubchannelID
}

func (c Channel) Remove(sid SocketID) {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()

    if _, ok := c.sockets[sid]; ok {
        delete(c.sockets, sid)
    }
    if _, ok := c.subchannels[sid]; ok {
        delete(c.subchannels, sid)
    }
}
```